Can I disable refreshParent when I submit a popup form?
I have a page that have multiple sections of activities in datatables that can edit/add activities as popup. When submitting, it refreshes the whole page and loads everything again. I just need a specific section to refresh or let me handle the refresh on success. I tried using some events here, but could not prevent it. It seems refreshParent comes first before others.
CiviCRM AJAX

Can you say more about the page? Is it a SearchKit display, or actually the old jQuery Datatables?

@Coleman Thank for the feedback. It is the jQuery DataTables using ajax to populate the rows.

The button had classes: "action-item crm-hover-button". The page is basically the Case Page.

Still trying to understand the exact context. Is this like your personal copy of the CiviCase code that you've put into an extension? Or is it literally CiviCase?

Your first line of debugging is probably to look at your "console" for a javascript error. An ajax request is normally intercepted by some javascript before it gets handled as a POST - in your case, it appears it's not getting intercepted. You may also see a difference if you turn off javascript aggregation. Different browsers handle javascript errors in different ways as well ...

Thank you for the feedback. I will have to search more on that.
